# PHP Symfony 3 - POST variables unavailable in controller

Tags: php, json, symfony, decode

I am trying to consume a JSON string built with the JS function `JSON.stringify(objects)`. On my working local version, it is working, but on the server it raises the following error:

> invalid argument supplied for foreach

After some investigations, the $POST table is empty. But in the browser console, the data is sent with the query.

Here is the content of the request:

```
rencontres:[{"id":"1","m":"","f":"0-2","e":"","p":"","status":"3","st":false,"si":false,"se":false,"sp":false,"ss":false}]
```

Here is the JSON string contained in `$GET['rencontres']` (accessed by `$request->get("rencontres")`):

```
[{"id":"1","m":"","f":"0-2","e":"","p":"","status":"3","st":false,"si":false,"se":false,"sp":false,"ss":false}]
```

which seems correct.

Here some var_dump results:
    var_dump($renontres) gives [][]

```
var_dump($request->get("rencontres") gives also [][]
```

here is the method itself:

```
public function postSaveRencontre(Request $request){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $rencontres = json_decode($request->get("rencontres"), true);
    //log struff
    foreach ($rencontres as $key => $r) {
        //blablabla
    }
    //return statement
}
```

and here the AJAX statement (url is correct):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"url",
    data: {rencontres:JSON.stringify(rencontres)},
    success:function(data){
        console.log("save performed");
    }
});
```

Comment: Does `var_dump($rencontres)` give you any clues?

Comment: it gives "[ ][ ]"

Comment: Dump the variable `$rencontres` before your `foreach()`-statement. Also try to remove `stripcslashes()`.

Comment: run `var_dump($request->get("rencontres"))` what does that give you?

Comment: Does `var_dump($rencontres)` give you `[ ][ ]`? That's odd.

Comment: What's the PHP version on your shared hosting? Also is JSON enabled? (I know it's compiled in by default but it's theoretically possible to have had PHP installed with JSON not enabled).

Comment: one of the many reasons why they invented Docker.

Comment: are you using a framework? where are you getting `$request` from?

Comment: @apokryfos PHP7 I think (on my Mamp it is 5.x I guess)

Comment: @CodeGodie yep, Symfony 3

Comment: Are you looking at the result of `var_dump()` on the actual page or through the browsers console?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson in a log file

Comment: Are you passing the `$request` as a parameter of your method? Show your entire Symfony controller's method so that we can dissect it better.

Comment: @CodeGodie Here u r :)

Comment: what version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: shouldnt it be `$request->query->get('rencontres');`

Comment: or `$request->request->get('rencontres')`

Comment: @CodeGodie I works in my local Mamp version... which is exactly the same... Still, let me try on the server :)

Comment: @CodeGodie same error with your both statements :(

Comment: did you clear your Symfony cache? `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: yep, I just cleared it once again: same error :(

Comment: In that method, what if you do a straight PHP $_GET to test if youre actually able to catch those requests, so do `var_dump($_GET['rencontres']);` and let me know what you get

Comment: array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(11) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["m"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["f"]=>
    string(3) "0-2"
    ["e"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["p"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["st"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["si"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["se"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["sp"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["ss"]=>
    bool(false)
  }

Comment: after investigation $_POST array is empty...

Comment: Yes the problem is that the post variables are not passed in the query... But in the browser console the content is well present...

Answer (score 0):

Hi I Think that i get the same problem in my application
the cause of this problem is that ajax send data as content-type application/json on post 
to Fix this poblem you have to add this code to your Action

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
$request->request->replace($data);
dump($request->request->get("rencontres"))
```

you have to add this ligne to all your Action that has POST
or Think to create a service to transform Your Json request

Comment: It says Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::replace() must be of the type array, null given.
$request->getContent() seems to be null... which is wired

Comment: if you inspect the network do you see the data in Request Payload

Comment: Normaly if you dump $request->getContent(); you have to see your data in json format